How can i update a recurrence rule using Regex
I have a recurrence rule in the format specified by RFC 2445, and I need to update the start date and end date. Here are some examples:

DTSTART:20240422T000000Z
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20240427T235959Z
DTSTART:20220826T040000Z
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20220826T040000Z
DTSTART:20220501T000000Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;UNTIL=20230114T235959Z
DTSTART:20220930T040000Z
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20220930T040000Z

Since I couldn't find any library capable of this, I'm planning to create a function to update the start date and end date.
I created the following function
    private static string UpdateRecurrenceStartDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string recurrence)
{
    var pattern = @"(DTSTART:[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z).*?(UNTIL=[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z)";
    var updatedRecurrence = Regex.Replace(recurrence, pattern, $"DTSTART:{startDate.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")} UNTIL={endDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")}");
    
    return updatedRecurrence;
}

It's not working the start Date and endDate are not updated

Are the startDate and endDate parameters modified versions of the dates in the rule or something completely different?

Yes, they are different

Are you intending to keep the rest of the rule/string as is? FREQ, INTERVAL, etc.

All I want to do is update the start date and end date. I intended to utilize a library to generate the entire string, but unfortunately, I couldn't find any relevant information in C#.

Since you are replacing two different date strings, you'll need to run .Replace() twice... once for each date. In the second .Replace() you need to pass the results from the first .Replace(). Also, you don't need to match the entire string since you only want to replace the dates.
I added a separate regex for DTSTART and UNTIL date strings and then added a second .Replace(). I also moved the "Z" at the end of the time string outside of .ToString(). The updated method looks like
private static string UpdateRecurrenceStartDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string recurrence)
{
    var patternStart = @"DTSTART:\d{8}T\d{6}Z";
    var updatedRecurrence = Regex.Replace(recurrence, patternStart, $"DTSTART:{startDate.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")}Z");
    var patternUntil = @"UNTIL=\d{8}T\d{6}Z";
    updatedRecurrence = Regex.Replace(updatedRecurrence, patternUntil, $"UNTIL={endDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")}Z");

    return updatedRecurrence;
}

I tested it using your sample strings and the code below
string[] rules = ["DTSTART:20240422T000000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20240427T235959Z",
                  "DTSTART:20220826T040000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20220826T040000Z",
                  "DTSTART:20220501T000000Z RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;UNTIL=20230114T235959Z" ,
                  "DTSTART:20220930T040000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20220930T040000Z"];
foreach (string rule in rules)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"old: {rule}");
    string newRule = UpdateRecurrenceStartDate(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), rule);
    Console.WriteLine($"new: {newRule}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

and it output
old: DTSTART:20240422T000000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20240427T235959Z
new: DTSTART:20000101T000000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20010101T235959Z

old: DTSTART:20220826T040000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20220826T040000Z
new: DTSTART:20000101T000000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20010101T235959Z

old: DTSTART:20220501T000000Z RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;UNTIL=20230114T235959Z
new: DTSTART:20000101T000000Z RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;UNTIL=20010101T235959Z

old: DTSTART:20220930T040000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20220930T040000Z
new: DTSTART:20000101T000000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20010101T235959Z


It looks like the regular expression pattern you're using might not be capturing the dates correctly.
The following revision of your function adjusts it to capture the dates correctly:
private static string UpdateRecurrenceStartDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string recurrence)
{
    var pattern = @"(DTSTART:[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z).*?(UNTIL=[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z)";
    var updatedRecurrence = Regex.Replace(recurrence, pattern, $"DTSTART:{startDate.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")} UNTIL:{endDate.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")}");
            
    return updatedRecurrence;
}

I also removed the AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1) from endDate as it seemed unnecessary.
